# Can I control the order of HTML elements by class name?

Tags: html, css

I have several divs with fixed class names:

```
<div class="type-a"></div>
<div class="type-b"></div>
<div class="type-c"></div>
```

There can be multiples of these and these divs are not always in order. They are dynamically added.

```
<div class="type-a"></div>
<div class="type-b"></div>
<div class="type-c"></div>
<div class="type-c"></div>
<div class="type-b"></div>
<div class="type-b"></div>
<div class="type-c"></div>
<div class="type-a"></div>
```

I want to group all the `type-a` and `type-b` divs and show them in front of `type-c` divs (which can be done by floating `type-a` & `type-b` to the right and `type-c` to the left). Also between `type-a` and `type-b` I want to show the `type-a` divs first. And `type-b` second.

Without re-arranging the above HTML or using JavaScript, I'm trying to get this output:

```
[type-a] [type-a] [type-b] [type-b] [type-b] [type-c] [type-c] [type-c]
```

Is this possible with just CSS?

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txv2j6bs/6/) with the divs floated left and right. The ordering that needs to happen now is between `type-a` and `type-b`.

Comment: @sol super ;) taken back! sorry :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` and the `order` property:

```css
.container>div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.type-a {
  order: 1;
}

.type-b {
  order: 2;
}

.type-c {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="type-a">A</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-a">A</div>
</div>
```

Order also works with `Grid`:

```css
.container>div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.type-a {
  order: 1;
}

.type-b {
  order: 2;
}

.type-c {
  order: 3;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20px);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="type-a">A</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-b">B</div>
  <div class="type-c">C</div>
  <div class="type-a">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `flex` display:

```css
.container {
display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
}

.type-a {
order:1;
}

.type-b {
order:2;
}

.type-c {
order:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="type-a">a</div>
<div class="type-b">b</div>
<div class="type-c">c</div>
<div class="type-c">c</div>
<div class="type-b">b</div>
<div class="type-b">b</div>
<div class="type-c">c</div>
<div class="type-a">a</div>
</div>
```